# Oracle stored procedure with a query where some search criteria may be missing

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c and have a stored procedure that accepts 4 input fields, queries database using the same and return result set. However, these 4 input fields are user input values from front-end so user may or may not enter all 4 input fields. I would need to execute stored procedure with whatever values it receives and ignore the rest.

stored procedure definition:

```
procedure retrieve_data (
p_sn_no in integer,
p_name in varchar2,
p_city in varchar 2,
p_phone in integer,
return_msg out number)
is begin
  select count(*) into return_msg from <table_name> 
    where sn_no=p_sn_no and name=p_name
    and city=p_city and phone=p_phone
end
```

The requirement is to invoke the above stored procedure with any or all of the input parameters but how to prepare the `select` statement within the stored procedure with all or few input fields, something like `select count(*) into return_msg from <table_name> where sn_no=p_sn_no` instead of passing all 4 input fields?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure call still passes all input parameter values, only those that are not provided by the user will have NULL values, so your query should take advantage of that:

```
select count(*) into return_msg from <table_name> 
where (sn_no=p_sn_no or p_sn_no is null) 
  and (name=p_name or p_name is null) -- etc.
  ...
```

Comment: You need to bracket the conditions together, as the default precedence will give different results.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thanks, you're right of course, and explicit grouping of operators is a good habit anyway. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
procedure retrieve_data 
  (return_msg out number, 
   p_sn_no in integer DEFAULT NULL, 
   p_name in varchar2 DEFAULT NULL, 
   p_city in varchar2  DEFAULT NULL, 
   p_phone in integer DEFAULT NULL) 
is 
begin 
  select count(*) 
    into return_msg 
    from 
    where sn_no = NVL(p_sn_no, sn_no) 
      and name = NVL(p_name, name) 
      and city = NVL(p_city, city) 
      and phone = NVL(p_phone, phone) 
end
```

Comment: @KrishT then, you may consider to accept the answer dear friend :)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, yes, this answer is working but i didnt find an option to close this question by accepting the answer

Comment: Are `sn_no`, `name`, `city` and  `phone` all defined as `NOT NULL` columns? `phone = phone` is only true where `phone` is not null.